# why leonardo bootloader is bigger than UNO?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-leonardo, bootloader

Apparently leonardo and UNO are very similar boards.

However, despite that both have the same flash memory size, Leonardo bootloader is considerably bigger than UNO bootloader (4KB vs 0.5KB).

what would be the reason? it is there any way to use smaller bootloader in leonardo?

Uno specs: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno

Leonardo specs: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLeonardo

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Apparently leonardo and UNO are very similar boards.

No, they are very, very different.

The Uno uses an external USB-UART bridge. This means that the bootloader code only has to read from the UART in order to program the device.

The Leonardo has USB support built into the MCU. This means that the bootloader must contain an entire USB Device stack in order to process the USB packets and then pass the payload to the programming routines.